# how to change values in each string of an array of strings every N lines

Tags: javascript, arrays

in the array of strings, values must be changed every 5 lines ( R=>G=>O, R remains for 5 times, O for 1 time, G for 5 times)

input:

```
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
```

output :

```
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....G............O......
....G............R......
....G............R......
....G............R......
....G............R......
....O............R......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....R............G......
....G............O......
....G............R......
....G............R......
....G............R......
....G............R......
....O............R......
```

I'm sorry for my unreadable code(just delected it), I've really tried to make it better.

Comment: Would be really helpful to describe your problem better. I dont really grasp what you're trying to do. Maybe a couple of pairs of input and output examples that you wish the function to produce..?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the "road" and the expected output of that "road"

Comment: @entio please check my question, I've added more strings

Comment: You should have asked this question with the original problem statement which, I believe, should be something like **Traffic Lights**. Try this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-traffic-lights-dqcog). If it works perfectly, can you copy the code, edit your answer and put that code as an alternate solution (keep your original answer) and mark that as "Accepted"? Feel free to update the question title to a more suitable one. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for helping, I've solved it by myself

```
var array = '....R............G......'.split('');
n = 20;

var redStates = 'RRRRRGGGGGO'.split('');
var greenStates = 'GGGGGORRRRR'.split('');
var orangeStates = 'ORRRRRGGGGG'.split('');
var newArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 var step = i % 11;
   var line = [];

 for(var j = 0; j < array.lenght; j++){
    console.log(array[j]);
  if (array[j] == '.')
   line.push('.');

  if (array[j] === 'R')
   line.push(redStates[step]);
  if (array[j] === 'G')
   line.push(greenStates[step]);
  if (array[j] === 'O')
   line.push(orangeStates[step]);
 }
 newArray.push(line);
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: @AjeetShah I'm sure you could suggest a better decision

Comment: I've put your code into a Stack Snippet. It has a syntax error (missing `}`) and an undeclared variable (`n`). Also, in order to be useful to others, answers should *explain* what they're doing, not just be code dumps.

Comment: @Lydia I have suggested my solution in a comment under the question. Does that help?